# How to find all the paths starting from one vertex to an end vertex in a directed graph using jGrapht?

Tags: java, jgrapht

I need to find all the paths starting from one vertex and traverse in a path until that path ends.

Comment: It's a bit of a generic question. Can you provide more details or an example?

Comment: Let's say I need to identify multiple inheritance. So, there are class names as a String value (Which is a vertex of the graph) and they are mapped according to the inheritance hierarchy. By identifying the paths I can identify the inheritance levels and stuff. So I think this might be a help

Comment: Your questions is simply too vague. Please do some effort and write a proper question. Which jgrapht methods have you looked into, and why weren't they suitable for your problem? Also, what kind of paths are you looking for, e.g. edge disjoint vs vertex disjoint paths?

Comment: I used a default directed graph and used Depth First iterator to traverse. This works well with cases where one vertex doesn't have multiple paths. That was to used to map inheritance hierarchy of Java classes and now I need to map inheritance hierarchy of c++ classes. As c++ has multiple inheritance I cannot solve the issue by using a previous one. That's why